# Get result ignoring null using UNION ALL operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, union-all

Here is my code:

```
select TRANSACTIONID, INFORMATION as "C_cntct", NULL as "C_nam"
from RETAILTRANSACTIONINFOCODETRANS as t
where INFOCODEID = 1009 and TRANSDATE = '2022-07-20'

UNION

select TRANSACTIONID, NULL, INFORMATION
from RETAILTRANSACTIONINFOCODETRANS as t
where INFOCODEID = 1010 and TRANSDATE = '2022-07-20'
group by TRANSACTIONID, INFORMATION
order by TRANSACTIONID, INFORMATION desc
```

I am getting result is:

| TRANSACTIONID | C_cntct | C_nam |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ST-EMP-ST-LHR-01-66079 | RASHID ALI | NULL |
| ST-EMP-ST-LHR-01-66079 | NULL | 0321-9439143 |
| ST-EMP-ST-LHR-01-66080 | SADAFSEHAR | NULL |
| ST-EMP-ST-LHR-01-66080 | NULL | 0345-4036448 |

But I want this result, with Null Ignore:

| TRANSACTIONID | C_cntct | C_nam |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ST-EMP-ST-LHR-01-66079 | RASHID ALI | 0321-9439143 |
| ST-EMP-ST-LHR-01-66080 | SADAFSEHAR | 0345-4036448 |

Comment: Your code uses `union` not `union all`?

Comment: Could you share a sample of the input table? and why you are selecting `C_nam`, `C_cntct` as null?

Comment: You are trying to take `C_cntct` from one row and take `C_nam` from another row. `UNION` will never combine columns from different rows. It will just stack rows from different queries.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need conditional aggregation (aka Pivot), although without sample input data it's hard to say for sure.

It's generally simpler to just use `MIN(CASE WHEN` for this, rather than using the explicit `PIVOT` syntax, which is rather limited.

```sql
SELECT
  trans.TRANSACTIONID,
  MIN(CASE WHEN trans.INFOCODEID = 1009 THEN trans.INFORMATION END) AS C_cntct,
  MIN(CASE WHEN trans.INFOCODEID = 1010 THEN trans.INFORMATION END) AS C_nam
FROM RETAILTRANSACTIONINFOCODETRANS AS trans
WHERE trans.INFOCODEID IN (1009, 1010)
  AND trans.TRANSDATE = '2022-07-20'
GROUP BY
  trans.TRANSACTIONID
ORDER BY
  trans.TRANSACTIONID;
```

Comment: Actually, this is the best scenario of what the OP trying to do 